# How to create trigger or procedure in Oracle express to automate values in a column of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

How can I enter the value in the `line_total` column that would be made by the account (`sales_line.line_total = product.unit_price * sales_line.line_qty`)?

I would like to have trigger or a procedure to automate this. When I enter the values in the columns, it automatically triggers the trigger, doing that calculation and inserting the result in the column `sales_line.line_total`.

I would also like to automate the column `sale.sale_total` which would be the sum of the values column `sales_line.line_total`. Can you make a trigger or procedure for these two questions?

can you help me?

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    product_id    NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    category_id   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    p_desc        VARCHAR2(40),
    cpu           VARCHAR2(14),
    ram           VARCHAR2(14),
    capacity      VARCHAR2(14),
    screen_size   VARCHAR2(14),
    battery       VARCHAR2(14),
    unit_price    NUMBER(7, 2),
    colour        VARCHAR2(14),
    qty_stock     NUMBER(4)
);
ALTER TABLE product ADD CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY ( product_id );

CREATE TABLE sale (
    sale_id       NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    sale_date     DATE,
    customer_id   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    employee_id   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    sale_total    NUMBER(7, 2)
);

ALTER TABLE sale ADD CONSTRAINT sale_pk PRIMARY KEY ( sale_id );

CREATE TABLE sales_line (
    sale_id      NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    product_id   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    line_qty     NUMBER(4),
    line_total   NUMBER(7, 2)
);

ALTER TABLE sales_line ADD CONSTRAINT index_3 PRIMARY KEY ( sale_id,
                                                            product_id );

ALTER TABLE product
    ADD CONSTRAINT product_p_category_fk FOREIGN KEY ( category_id )
        REFERENCES p_category ( category_id );

ALTER TABLE sale
    ADD CONSTRAINT sale_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY ( customer_id )
        REFERENCES customer ( customer_id );

ALTER TABLE sale
    ADD CONSTRAINT sale_employee_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ( employee_id )
        REFERENCES employee ( employee_id );

ALTER TABLE sales_line
    ADD CONSTRAINT sales_line_product_fk FOREIGN KEY ( product_id )
        REFERENCES product ( product_id );

ALTER TABLE sales_line
    ADD CONSTRAINT sales_line_sale_fk FOREIGN KEY ( sale_id )
        REFERENCES sale ( sale_id );
```

Here are the triggers I have written so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_line_total_ai AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    lt_value NUMBER(7,2);
BEGIN
    SELECT product.unit_price INTO lt_value FROM product;
    UPDATE sales_line
    SET line_total = :NEW.line_qty * lt_value
   -- SET line_total = (line_qty * :NEW.unit_price)   
    WHERE product_id = :NEW.product_id;

    --UPDATE sales_line
      --  SET line_total = (line_qty * :OLD.unit_price)
        --WHERE product.product_id = :OLD.product_id;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sale_total_ai AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN     
    UPDATE sale     
    SET sale_total = (sale_total + :NEW.line_total)   
    WHERE sale_id = :NEW.sale_id;

    UPDATE sale
        SET sale_total = (sale_total + :OLD.line_total)
        WHERE sale_id = :OLD.sale_id;
END;
```

Comment: Storing totals normally goes against all normalisation “rules”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have major two issues.  The first (as noted in other answers) is that the first trigger should be a *before* trigger that modifies the records in place.  The logic for the trigger can also be simplified (as below)

The second issues is that you should be *subtracting* the `old` values in the second trigger.  So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_line_total_ai
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT :NEW.line_qty * p.unit_price
    INTO :NEW.line_total
    FROM product p
    WHERE p.product_id = :NEW.product_id;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sale_total_ai
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN     
    UPDATE sale     
        SET sale_total = (sale_total + :NEW.line_total)   
        WHERE sale_id = :NEW.sale_id;

    UPDATE sale
        SET sale_total = (sale_total - :OLD.line_total)
        WHERE sale_id = :OLD.sale_id;
END;
```

Note that the second trigger has two updates.  This allows the `sale_id` to be updated.  You *can* wrap this into a single update if you like:

```
    UPDATE sale     
        SET sale_total = (sale_total + 
                          (CASE WHEN sale_id = :NEW.sale_id THEN :NEW.line_total ELSE 0 END) -
                          (CASE WHEN sale_id = :OLD.sale_id THEN :OLD.line_total ELSE 0 END)
                         )  
        WHERE sale_id IN (:OLD.sale_id, :NEW.sale_id);
```

You need to be very careful with expressing this logic so it works for both updates and inserts.  You should probably extend this trigger to work for `delete`s as well.

Comment: INSERT INTO sales_line (sale_id, product_id, line_qty, line_total)
VALUES (2, 24, 1, 0)

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.TRG_LINE_TOTAL_BIU' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Comment: Thank everyone  and Gordon Linoff for help me.  I tried, but it return that error.  I'm new here.  So, sorry for some mistakes.  Can you tell me how fix that error? Happy New Year.  I'm tried do that for some days.

Comment: @DViga . . . Neither of these triggers is called `TRG_LINE_TOTAL_BIU`.  That error can happen when the queries   in the trigger cannot be recompiled -- often because of a mistake in a column or table name.  You need to double check the queries to be sure they are correct.  They look correct.

Comment: APC and @Gordon Linoff I did exactly as Gordon put that, and I checked and the error is the same. And I removed the UPDATE and put BEFORE instead AFTER. Could be, something about the sale_id and product_id in the sales_line table be (PF) - composite keys? Because I don't understand where the error I just put the insert code: INSERT INTO sales_line (sale_id, product_id, line_qty, line_total) VALUES (2, 24, 1, 0). Can you guys help me please? I put the tables above, so the column names and set-up is ok with the insert code.

Comment: @DViga . . . Unfortunately, the online sites that allow testing of code don't seem to work for Oracle SQL with triggers.  That makes it hard to figure out what is happening.  I wonder if there is some sort of permissions issue when revalidating the trigger.

Comment: Sorry guys now it's works.  I think the error was because I had no do update or commit, I don't know.  I just remove everything and put again.  And go.  Thank you guys, now I will test the 3 triggers.  Guys **@Gordon Linoff** and **APC**.  You're the best.  Thank you so much I'm very happy, because I was tried and searching for many places and you guys helped me a lot.  I was already feeling bad trying. and this is serious. You guys really helped a lot and I have no words to thank you for helping me!  ** But the column sale.sale_total is null.  the trigger no updated with the equation **.

Comment: In the second trigger no need some equation like this:  sale.sale_total = (sales_line.line_qty + sales_line.line_total) ? @Gordon Linoff and APC.  Because the total value in the sale table is the sum of the line_qty + line_total in the sales_line table.  The first trigger is working well

Comment: I put here @APC. The 2 comments above.

Comment: I tried do that in the second trigger:  
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sale_total_ai AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE sale
        SET sale_total= (sale_total + :NEW.line_total)         
        WHERE sale_id IN (:NEW.sale_id);
END;

In the first line worked, but no more in the others line in the sale table.  Do you can tell me why?  Thank you  @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

To update sale_line you must use a before trigger, then update is not necesary over this table. Only asign value to :New.line_total.
To update sale you can do it in the dame trigger.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I didn't understand what means.  Can you show me please?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use following code instead. Please note the keyword "Before" instead of After in both triggers definitions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_line_total_ai BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        lt_value NUMBER(7,2);
    BEGIN
        SELECT product.unit_price INTO lt_value FROM product;
        UPDATE sales_line
        SET line_total = :NEW.line_qty * lt_value
       -- SET line_total = (line_qty * :NEW.unit_price)   
        WHERE product_id = :NEW.product_id;

        --UPDATE sales_line
          --  SET line_total = (line_qty * :OLD.unit_price)
            --WHERE product.product_id = :OLD.product_id;
    END;


    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_sale_total_ai BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sales_line
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN     
        UPDATE sale     
        SET sale_total = (sale_total + :NEW.line_total)   
        WHERE sale_id = :NEW.sale_id;

        UPDATE sale
            SET sale_total = (sale_total + :OLD.line_total)
            WHERE sale_id = :OLD.sale_id;
    END;
```